# MySQL query and php edit

Tags: php, mysql

I have many database entries, each containing a value.

I want to show some statistics regarding those values, so I should be able to say:

- how many entries (rows) have the value between 0 and 5,
- how many entries (rows) have the value between 6 and 10,
- how many entries (rows) have the value between 11 and 20,
- how many entries (rows) have the value more then 20.

(the values above where given only as an example)

Let's say I'll have like 6-7 intervals that I want to group the values by. Can I do this in a single MySQL query? If yes, how can I acces the grouped values using <strike>photoshop</strike> PHP aftewards?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**
Seems like the query is actually harder. I have 2 columns (val1 and val2). I want the query to count how many items have val1/val2 (val1 divided by val2) between an interval...

Comment: OMG, I think I should take a break... :)) I meant, php lol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT 
   SUM(col BETWEEN 0 AND 5) AS 0_to_5,
   SUM(col BETWEEN 6 AND 10) AS 6_to_10,
```

etc. etc.

re: your edit:

```
  SELECT 
   SUM(val1/val2 BETWEEN 0 AND 5) AS 0_to_5,
   SUM(val1/val2 BETWEEN 6 AND 10) AS 6_to_10,
```

Comment: +1 From there it's just a simple step of grabbing a screenshot of the outputted values and pasting them into photoshop.

Comment: @Cristy: I know. I was joking :)

Comment: I know you were joking, I was talking to Frank; I've added something to the query :))

Answer (score 3):

If the ranges you're splitting the counts up into are of the same size, you can use the modulo operator:

```
SELECT MOD(col, 5), COUNT(col)
FROM ...
WHERE ...
GROUP BY MOD(col, 5)
```

which would group everything into a 5-per-category type thing automatically, and handle an unlimited range of categories.

If the ranges are different sizes, then you'll have to generate a large case/if-then-else type construct to check for each range individually.